# Form not Rending Correctly in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

So I have this form written in haml

```
 = form_tag assign_photographers_path, class: "col-md-12 assign-photographers-form-#{portfolio.id}" do
   = hidden_field_tag :portfolio_id, portfolio.id
   = hidden_field_tag :user_id_1, "", class: "user_id_1"
   = hidden_field_tag :user_id_2, "", class: "user_id_2"
   = label_tag :user, "Begin typing to assign the first photographer:"
   %br
   .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
   = text_field_tag :user, nil, class: "form-control photographer-search", data_id: portfolio.id
   .clearfix
   %div{class: "photographer-list#{portfolio.id} col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"}
     %h3 Chosen photographers
   .clearfix
   %br
   = submit_tag "Assign Photographers", :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

In the source code it shows

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/photographers/assign" class="col-md-12 assign-photographers-form-19" method="post"></form>
```

The contents of the form are then printed below the form. I have no idea why it's printing outside of the form tags. What's wrong with the code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just for my own sanity, have you tried:  `= form_tag(assign_photographers_path, { class: "col-md-12 assign-photographers-form-#{portfolio.id}" }) do` to set up the form?

Comment: No, I have not. First chance I get I'll try it.

Comment: Try that and see what you get.

Comment: did that work or are you still having issues?

Comment: Not sure. Haven't had a chance to check it. I assure you when I do I'll let you do and give you points.